# Can I access global ES5 variable inside ES6 module?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to gradually modularize and rewrite in ES6 a project written in ES5.
With this I have common scripts with classes and variables as well as modules using the type = "module" attribute when loading ES6 modules.

Example:

```
<script src="constants.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
<script src="banners.js" type="module"></script>
```

My problem is the following, I want to access inside the module "banners.js" the constants of the file "constants.js"

At first I thought this was possible, as linux chrome and firefox accept calling a global variable within the banners.js module, but unfortunately the iPad / iOS11 chrome does not accept and is accusing error: **ReferenceError: Can't find variable**

Unfortunately I can not convert the constants.js file in a module to use the export / import syntax because these constants are used in ES5 parts of the code that can not yet be converted to ES6 modules and could not read the constants if I convert the constants into an ES6 module.

Is there a way to access the global scope from within an ES6 module? Or some other way to get the variables from the file "constants.js"?

Maybe this is a chrome bug for iOS and the Linux version shows the correct behavior?

This difference in behavior between operating systems really left me confused as to the scope of the modules and their ability to access the global scope.

Comment: It should work as expected, the error is somewhere else.

Comment: Convert `constants.js` to a UMD module and include it as `type="module"` here but as a normal script where it needs to be exposed as ES5 globals.

Comment: I discovered the problem. My constants.js file has some constants defined with the new ES6 types "const" and "let", strangely iOS chrome can not read inside a module, global variables defined with "const" and "let", only works if I change everything to "var". 
I still can not tell which chrome is with the correct behavior in this case, whether Linux or iOS.

Comment: @JonasWilms: What did you mean? I have the same problem that I have to access ES5 `var foo` from an ES6 module. Do you mean that this is possible by default?